# Snap application icons aren't found in Dash

Tags: unity, icons, snap

I installed a snap application, Skrifa, but the icon didn't show up in Dash. The apps, however, can be launched from Terminal. Is there any way to solve this bug?

[image: The blank icon that show up when the app is running]

Comment: This could be a bug in unity - many others have reported that icons don't appear sometimes. Alternatively it could be that the desktop file supplies by Skrifa is mal-formed. There is one mistake in their desktop file, but not sure it's enough to make it (and the icon) fail to be used.

Comment: HI, thanks for your explanation @popey . I do appreciate it. So, is there any practical way to solve this problem yet?